# How to know property names and apis to add effects to layers on After Effects?

Tags: adobe, extendscript, after-effects

I am really having a hard time looking for information about how to use the scripting language  (called extendedscript but it its javascript) in Adobe After Effects.

I find pages like this ones:

1. https://www.aenhancers.com/
2. https://github.com/fabianmoronzirfas
3. http://docs.aenhancers.com/
4. https://blogs.adobe.com/creativecloud/files/2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf

But they lack examples of very simple things. Especially the scripting guide! What I'd like to know is how to find a way to detect the proper "naming" of properties to know how to assing them.

I. E. I would like to create a key frame without blur on a text layer in second 5, and with blur in second 10. It looks like something simple... it should be like this:

```
var myProject = app.project;
var myComposition = myProject.activeItem;
var myTextLayer = myComposition.layers.addText("new_text_layer");
myTextLayer.addProperty("blur").setValueAtTime(5, 0);
myTextLayer.addProperty("blur").setValueAtTime(10, 60);
```

However, I cannot find the proper literal name to add effects, I don't know how to add property "blur" cause I don't know the word the scripting language uses for "blurring"!!! That's the same for almost everything.

So... How can I find out how to programatically set properties to layers on After Effects?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effects are properties of layers and can be accessed as specified [here](http://docs.aenhancers.com/properties/propertybase/#propertybase). To access an effect you need to know the effect's name. You can then use

```
var effect1 = app.project.item(1).layer(1).effect("effect name")("effect param name");
```

Since there is no limit on how many effects are available for AE (e.g. there are at least half a dozen blur effects, but no effect called just "blur"), the individual effects are not built-in to the extendscript language, so you need to know how to specify each one. The Extendscript Toolkit's [data browser](http://estk.aenhancers.com/2%20-%20ExtendScript%20Toolkit/debugging-in-the-toolkit.html) is useful for this, because you can have a live instance of AE going and look through the data structures.

Another useful tool is the redefinery's [rd:scripts](http://www.redefinery.com/ae/rd_scripts/) package. It contains 51 really useful scripts for developers and it's free. One in particular is the [gimme prop path](http://www.redefinery.com/ae/view.php?item=rd_GimmePropPath) script that will tell you the full path for a selected property.